# Blender Sverchok - Finding the projection of a vertex on another mesh

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

I need some help in Sverchok.
I have a mesh plane (**A**) with a vertex (**V**) on it.
I would like to find the point on another mesh (**B**) where the "projection" of the vertex in the normal direction would hit that second mesh.

I was looking trough all the Sverchok nodes but I couldn't find an obvious solution.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks **bstnhnsl** and also thanks to **Erindale**! Both of you pointed to Analyzers -> Raycaster and this works quite nicely. I just placed Susanne to the calculated point:

[image]